# What to do if you don't understand someone's English and he doesn't understand yours

Tags: support, answers, non-english-speakers

Today I answered someone's question and they made a comment I didn't quite understand. I told them to REPHRASE the question and it seems like they confused it with REFRESH. Thinking that the comment chain would become longer if I tried to make them understand my point, I stopped commenting. My question is that is there a flag or any other option for this kind of situation?

Here's the link for that particular comment : [how to add the new api level in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11759227/how-to-add-the-new-api-level-in-android/11759283#comment15612508_11759283)

Answer (score 8):

No, there's no flag for for this, neither is there a need for a flag. If the person you're communicating to doesn't understand what you're mentioning, then you should clarify. In this specific case, instead of mentioning "please rephrase" you could've mentioned

> please edit your question and mention exactly what you want to do

or the like.